# how to translate a URL address in PHP?

Tags: php

I have a PHP based website that has selections of fruit names in a different language.  For example, Orange is written with a completely different language that the URL can't read it.  Let's say that the name Orange is "&@%" in that language.

What I wanted to do is,

when '&@%' is selected in the combobox,
'&@%' is translated to 'Orange' so that the URL will be

```
http://example.com/Orange
```

instead of

```
http://example.com/&@%
```

Comment: use `value` attribute in `option` tag.

Comment: Make array and use key value.

Comment: I can't follow you. You talk about selections (select box?) and about  nice URL?? If using a slect box, your URL becomes `https://domain/page?name=value`.

Comment: Answered. Check it, the text that lies between option's tag is the text which is seen by the user & the text in value it only for programming purpose. It will not be visible to user.

Comment: Also consider using [urlencode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) function to allow special characters in URL. That would solve your problem with URL readability.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="select">
<option value="Orange">&@%</option>
</select>
```

PHP code:

```
echo $_GET["select"]; //Returns Orange
```

instead of orange returns its value, Then Orange will appear in your URL instead of &@%.

Answer (score -1):

Code:

`<select>
    <option value="&@%">Orange</option>
    ....
</select>`

And take `value` as URL part.

Comment: Please provide full answer, that will help OP

Comment: @AhmedAli likewise - _yours_ currently doesn’t do a very good job at that either. (OP is asking about what the URL contains, that would be GET - you are writing stuff that contains $_POST …)